# Is this sufficient to prove that $xe^x$ is invertible and its inverse is differentiable from $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis

If we have function $f(x) = xe^x$, is it enough to say that because this function  is one-to-one and strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$, that it is indeed invertible? I know the Inverse Function Theorem is only valid for local points so I know that we have to involve the fact that this is strictly increasing as well. Or do I need a more rigorous proof for this part?

In addition, I also want to show that its inverse which is the Lambert's W function is also differentiable on the same interval. I know that in order to prove differentiability, we must be able to put it into this form: $\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{f(x+h) - f(h)}{h}}$ but how can we do this for a function that isn't easily definable in the first place?

Finally, how would we compute $(f^{-1})'(e)$?

Comment: one-to-one is enough to say $f$ is invertible. Also, note that if $f'(f^{-1}(x))>0$, then $(f^{-1})'(x)=(f'(f^{-1}(x)))^{-1}$. Try proving this using chain rule.

Comment: Hmm I am a little confused. How does this continue the proof exactly? I only see it becoming more cluttered.

Comment: Differentiate $x=f(f^{-1}(x))$ and use inverse function theorem.

Comment: But wouldn't that only prove differentiability at that point only? Or would that imply that it works for all $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: $x\in(0,\infty)$ is arbitrary so you have differentiability on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Oh ok so basically $(f'(f^{-1}(x)))^{-1}$ is differentiable? Then, do we just replace $x$ with $e$ to get the answer for the last part?

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in(0,\infty)$. Since $f'(x)>0$, by inverse function theorem, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. To find the derivative, using chain rule, differentiate

$$x=f(f^{-1}(x))$$

giving

$$1=f'(f^{-1}(x))(f^{-1})'(x)$$

so

$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.$$

Comment: So for the last part, would we do $\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(e))}$? How can we compute this since we can't define it properly?

Comment: note that $f(1)=e$.

Comment: Ah, so we just do $\frac{1}{f'(1)}$? Ok that is much more doable!